# How to solve $\frac{d}{dx}\int_0^1 h(x,z)f(z) \, dz$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I have problem with <strike>solving</strike> simplifying the following <strike>equation</strike> expression,

$$\frac{d}{dx}\int_0^1 h(x,z)f(z)\,dz$$

I cannot deal with it, can anyone here help me out please?

Thank you guys

Comment: $\int_0^1\partial_xh(x,z)f(z)\ dz$

Comment: Under suitable hypothesis you can just take the derivative inside the integral.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That as it is written doesn't look much like an equation. Are you asking about the possible manipulations you can perform in order to simplify the expression? In that case, as suggested before, you can take the partial derivative $\frac{\partial}{\partial_{x}}$ inside the integral, as your integral is in the $z$ variable, not in $x$. Another way to look at this is to perform the integral $\int_{0}^{1}dzh(x,z)f(z)$ keeping $x$ constant, which gives:
\begin{eqnarray}
g(x)=\int_{0}^{1}dzh(x,z)f(z)
\end{eqnarray}
Then, once you know $g(x)$, you differenciate.